# Bootstrap time picker - End time not less than start time validation

Tags: javascript, angular

Bootstrap time picker -  End time not less than start time validation how to prevent user to select past time

```html
       <html>
        <head>  
        </head>
        <body>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <h1> Disable past time for end time input </h1>
         
              <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
         
                <input type='time' class="form-control" id="starttime" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
              <label for="end_time" class="col-form-label">End Time</label> 
                <input type='time' class="form-control" id="date" />
          
            <script>
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with Angular. Do you want to elaborate more on what you are trying to do? Maybe post some Angular code as well with the things you tried and explain a bit what is not working exactly?

Comment: sorry I have used  <input type='time' class="form-control" />in my angular component so I just want to disable end time scroll up / prevent user to select past time eg if current time is 12:00PM user can't select 11:00AM time

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know angular but you can this logic**

you can validate the time with [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) subtract function and subtract start time with an end time and check if the date changes that means end time is bigger then start time so don't update state

Comment: Thank you! I would like to work with moment js